# Cross-Promotion tools (framework or service) on iOS

Tags: ios, app-store, promotions, promoting

This is not really technical programing question, but I had good experience with Stack Overflow.

I have I few (around 5) iOS apps (some are games).

Now I would like to do cross promotion of my app in my other apps.

For offline solution I could write my own code for it, this is not problem for me.
But then problem is that when I have new app I need to update all my old apps.

So I am looking for some kind online solution.
Does something like this already exist ?
Like some framework with backend or some online service.

I am wiling even to use paid solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Check this pod
https://github.com/mfa01/CrossAdsWithFirebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that might help you.

```
https://github.com/danielamitay/DAAppsViewController
```

This will list out all the application developer by the company.

Comment: This look OK, for now. Do you know how do I find my ArtistId ?